# Create VM Using Azure CLI(Cloud Shell-Bash)

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli

I am trying to create VM in azure using Azure CLI(Cloud shell) bash using following command:-

```
az vm create -n AzCliVmOne -g azclirg -l eastus --vnet-name AzCliVmOneVn --subnet default --nsg AzCliVmOneNsg --public-ip-address AzCliVmOneIp --port 80,3389 --admin-username azshtestuser --admin-password azurevm@2020
```

While execute command it gives following error

```
az: error: unrecognized arguments: --port 80,3389
```

My question is how can create VM with open port in Azure CLI(Cloud Shell) bash?

I have also tried to find it out using following command

```
az vm create --help
```

Note:- I know how can we accomplish it using powershell. but i would like to know in Azure CLI bash command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`az vm create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-create) doesn't have a `--port` parameter.

To open inbound ports, you are probably looking for [`az vm open-port`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-open-port)
.

Since the `--port` parameter expects a port or range:

> The port or port range (ex: 80-100) to open inbound traffic to. Use '*' to allow traffic to all ports.

you will probably have to open up `80` and `3389` separately:

```
az vm open-port -g azclirg -n AzCliVmOne --port 80
az vm open-port -g azclirg -n AzCliVmOne --port 3389
```

Which you can run after creating your VM with `az vm create`.

Additionally, if you need to apply the rule to subnet level instead of NIC level, use the `--apply-to-subnet` parameter.